# IIS Script and file configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I would like to ask if how can I configure my IIS.
 I im using the default website and add Web Application in it.
 However, I'm having problem with the scripts.

In my Master Page, i have this code

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

 <link type="text/css" href="../../Scripts/toastr/toastr.min.css"  rel="Stylesheet" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/toastr/toastr.min.js"></script>

 <link type="text/css" href="../../Scripts/tipsy/src/stylesheets/tipsy.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/tipsy/src/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/IE8Compatibility/excanvas.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/IE8Compatibility/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/IE8Compatibility/respond.min.js"></script>
```

During runtime and accessing the page, i checked the source code. and i found this.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

 <link type="text/css" href="TAMS_PH/Scripts/toastr/toastr.min.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/toastr/toastr.min.js"></script>

 <link type="text/css" href="TAMS_PH/Scripts/tipsy/src/stylesheets/tipsy.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/tipsy/src/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/IE8Compatibility/excanvas.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/IE8Compatibility/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/IE8Compatibility/respond.min.js"></script>

 <link type="text/css" href="TAMS_PH/Styles/normalize.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/HRIS/HRIS.js"></script>

     <script src="../../Scripts/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../../Scripts/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" type="text/css" />
     <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../../Scripts/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" type="text/css" />
     <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../../Scripts/owl-carousel/owl.transitions.css" type="text/css" />
```

Notice the href tag with "TAMS_PH", that is accessible when I click  that link. However, the href tag with "../../" it says "404 - File or directory not found.".

Why Im getting error 404 when the files are in one directory and can be accessible in dev?

Note that "TAMS_PH" is the Web Application name. And we dont want to create another website with different port. Just inside the default web site of IIS.

Comment: prefix it with `~/` instead of `../../`

Comment: Hi, I already used your suggestion. However, it only works on <link> tag. why it's not applying in <script> tag?